# How synchronize the svg circle animation with timer?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Timer progress circle:
[image: Timer progress circle]

Hello folks, how can I synchronize the animation of decreasing the round line with the timer?
It's just that at the moment the animation ends faster than the timer.

```
let progressCircle = document.getElementById("progress-line");
let angle = 565;
let angleIncrement = 1;
const min = 0;

const lineAnimation = setInterval(() => {
    progressCircle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", angle + ", 20000");
    angle -= angleIncrement;
    if (angle <= min) {
        angle = 0;
        clearInterval(lineAnimation);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why not do your animation with SMIL? The browser will handle all the timing for you.

Comment: @robert-longson Thank you for info, I'll read about it :)